# How can I print the name of an object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code already written:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestBox {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        ShoeBox nike = new ShoeBox();
        Box present = new CandyBox(3,2,6);
        JewelryBox gift = new JewelryBox();
        Box pictures = new ShoeBox();
        Box skittles=new CandyBox(6,3,1);
        CandyBox dots=new CandyBox(3,2,1);
        Box jareds=new JewelryBox();
        List<Box> boxes=new ArrayList<Box>();
        boxes.add(nike);
        boxes.add(present);
        boxes.add(gift);
        boxes.add(pictures);
        boxes.add(skittles);
        boxes.add(dots);
        boxes.add(jareds);

        double temp=0;
        for (Box x:boxes)
            temp=temp+x.getVolume();

        for (int i=0;i<boxes.size();i++)
            System.out.println(boxes.get(i));

        double count=0;
        for (int k=0;k<boxes.size();k++)
            if ((boxes.get(0).getVolume())<(boxes.get(k).getVolume()))
                count=boxes.get(k).getVolume();
        System.out.println("The box with the biggest volume is the "+boxes.get((int)count)+".  The dimensions of the box"
                + "are "+boxes.get((int)count).getLength()+" x "+boxes.get((int)count).getWidth()+" x "
                +boxes.get((int)count).getHeight()+".");
    }
}
```

This is my tester for a class called Box.  The subclasses are shown in the creations of them.  What is the line of code needed to print out the name of the objects, such as skittles or jareds?

I need to print the "name" of the object with the largest volume. Let's say the object "nike" has the largest volume. The print statement at the bottom of the main should say "The box with the biggest volume is the nike. The dimensions are 12 x 12 x 12."

Comment: With *the name of the object* you mean how to get the simple name of the class? If that's so, then use `yourObject.getClass().getSimpleName()`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you explain what a simple name is?  I'm sorry, this is my first year learning code.  I'm looking for a way to print out the names of an object in the ArrayList boxes.

Comment: Well, an object doesn't have a name. A class do has a name. A class has a full name, which is the name of the package it belongs and the simple name of the class. For example, if your `TestBox` class is inside package `edu.yourcollege.noah`, then its full name would be `edu.yourcollege.noah.TestBox`, and the simple name would be `TestBox`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not looking to print the class name.  I need to print the "name" of the object with the largest volume.  Let's say the object "nike" has the largest volume.  The print statement at the bottom of the main should say "The box with the biggest volume is the nike.  The dimensions are 12 x 12 x 12."

Comment: Again, objects doesn't have a name. What you can do in such case is to determine which object match with your criteria (in this case, the object with the largest volume), store it in a temp variable and then use it depending on your needs.

Comment: And 'nike' isn't the name of an object. It is the name of a *variable,* and not one that is accessible at runtime by any means.

Comment: @EJP That's what I meant!  Thank you for making me realize that.  So the name of the variable isn't accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to print the name of the variable which meets certain criteria and is stored in your collection (your `List`). This **is not possible in Java** since at runtime you can't access to the name of the variables. In this cases, you should add a field in the class that helps you identify the object instance you're working with. This field could be an `int id` or `String name` (to keep it simple).

To make things easier, add this field in your `Box` class:

```
public class Box {
    //fields already declared here...
    //adding name field
    protected String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, fulfill this field when creating the objects:

```
//setting the name of the object just with the name of the variable
//just for understanding purposes
//you cannot access to the name of the variable at runtime, no matter what
//also, you need to change the constructor of each class accordingly
ShoeBox nike = new ShoeBox("nike");
Box present = new CandyBox("present",3,2,6);
JewelryBox gift = new JewelryBox("gift");
Box pictures = new ShoeBox("pictures");
Box skittles=new CandyBox("skittles",6,3,1);
CandyBox dots=new CandyBox("dots",3,2,1);
Box jareds=new JewelryBox("jareds");
```

And then, when an object matches with your criteria, you can use it for what you want/need e.g.

- Criteria: The largest volume
- What to do: display it's name to the user

Code:

```
double temp = 0;
Box boxWithLargestVolume = null;
for (Box box : boxes) {
    if (temp < x.getVolume()) {
        temp = x.getVolume();
        boxWithLargestVolume = box;
    }
}
if (boxWithLargestVolume != null) {
    System.out.println("The box with the largest volume is: "
        + boxWithLargestVolume.getName());
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that this assignment was assigned by my teacher.  She gave us the parameters for the constructors, and she gave us the client code for the tester, which included the instantiating of the boxes.

Comment: @NoahBarboza tell your professor that if you don't have a field to identify your object then there won't be any human way to recognize it. It all be in the software (and in our minds).